# Symfony 3 magic

Tags: php, symfony

I'm doing my first steps with Symfony.
I have a file DefaultController.php with the 2 identical functions:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/test/", name="test")
     */
    public function indexActionTest(Request $request)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Lucky number: it works!</body></html>');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/test2/", name="test2")
     */
    public function indexActionTest2(Request $request)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Lucky number: it works here as well!</body></html>');
    }
```

The fun thing is that the first one works, while the second one doesn't
http://triod.ru/project/web/test/
http://triod.ru/project/web/test2/
Even though the console says that the Route matches! How's that even possible?

Comment: Try to remove empty line before `indexActionTest2`, so the docblock is directly before method.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help(:

Comment: Well, I did a test and it works fine. It must be something else. Are these methods in the same controller? What's your routing confriguratino for these routes?

Comment: try naming the methods `indexTestAction()` and `indexTest2Action()`. (Action should be the final suffix)

Comment: @craigh there's no such requirement when you use annotations. It works that way in my test project.

Comment: Yes, there methods are in the same controller. What do you mean by "routing confriguratinon"? I have only one DefaultController and nothing more. I didn't change anything exept prov to dev after the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your public controller methods should always end in Action

```
[method]Action(Request $request){}
```

So for test2 you should name it like:

```
public function test2Action(Request $request)
```

Also you dont need to add name unless you are overriding another route:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/test/")
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Lucky number: it works!</body></html>');
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/test2/")
     */

    public function test2Action(Request $request)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Lucky number: it works here as well!</body></html>');
    }
```

Comment: Not true at all. ;-) You don't have to name it that way, when you use annotations. I've just veryfied this in my test project.  Also naming routes is useful if you want to do `path('test')` in Twig, do redirect in controller and so on. Route's name is a handler that use can use in many cases.

Comment: I didn't say have to, I said should, its best practice is what I meant. And if you use YML routing, symfony will look for a controller function named [method name]Action, if you had ActionTest in that scenario it would not work.

Also for testing path, may be its more convenient but again not a requirement, you get an auto generated route com_bundle_controller_action.

Comment: "If", but he doesn't use yml routing ;-) Anyway these  practices doesn't have anything to do with the problem here. So your'answer doesn't relate to the problem at all.